# render different collections and put them together afterwards

Tags: rendering, animation, gpu

I have a pretty heavy scene with several high poly objects which makes my PC already a little sluggish. However, I want to add some wind effects using a particle system. I was thinking about deleting everything out of the file except the lighting and camera movement and saving it as a new version. Then I would add the particle system, render it out and put the renders of the old and the new version together afterward using the Alpha Channel. Is that actually a thing? Is there a better solution to that problem?

Comment: Have you tried to do it with different collections, different view layers, and at the end mix them in the Compositor? It woul allow you to keep everything within the same file, and I guess if the collection is disabled for a given view layer, it should not affect the calculation speed